# Google Analytics tracking code on Rails app error pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I put my Google Analytics tracking code in my layout file, this of course does not embed it in my error pages (404.html, 500.html)

How can I properly track error pages without repeating the code? Are rack-based Google Analytics plugins the way to go? Or is there another preferred way?

Answer (score 0):

I had used this gem in the past https://github.com/leehambley/rack-google-analytics

Comment: This doesn't appear to use google analytics. I'd like to continue using google analytics.

Comment: Oops sorry this is the one for google analytics https://github.com/leehambley/rack-google-analytics

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I've got the script in my footer and it seems to track 404 pages. Under content->content dill down:
1.
/content/
17,819  16,542  00:04:56    92.67%  88.91%
2.
/
2,640   1,629   00:04:42    66.39%  57.20%
3.
/404.html?page=/content/jett-east&from=
110 105 00:01:26    93.33%  93.64%
4.
/user
68  41  00:00:59    0.00%   5.88%
5.
/user/
66  26  00:01:52    0.00%   9.09%
6.
/404.html?page=/content/tidewater&from=
9   7   00:04:11    33.33%  44.44%